# How to access files and variables from different directory in Terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

We have the below directory structure on the Linux system.

```
 /root
   ├─dirA
   │  ├─main.tf
   │  ├─terraform.tfvars
   │  └─variables.tf
   └─dirB
      └─main.tf
```

**==FIRST==**

We used the below snippet in `main.tf` file of `dirA` to create a local kubeconfig file.

```
resource "local_file" "kubeconfig" {
  content  = module.gke_auth.kubeconfig_raw
  filename = "./kubeconfig"
}
```

Now we would like to access this `kubeconfig` file in the `main.tf` file of `dirB` inside the following snippet. Please suggest how to do that?

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path    = "<PATH_TO_KUBECONFIG_FILE>"
}
```

**==SECOND==**

We have defined some variables inside the `terraform.tfvars` file of `dirA` and we would like to access those variables inside the `main.tf` file of `dirB`. Please suggest how to do this.

Comment: This isn't really how Terraform works. Why did you split your Terraform code into separate folders like this?

Comment: Thanks for the info, Mark. In first folder we are creating VPC and GKE cluster, in 2nd we are deploying Istio and in 3rd we deploy the application workloads.

Comment: You either need a top-level terraform template that uses these other folders as modules, or you need to use data lookups inside your terraform templates to lookup the resources that were created in your other templates.

Comment: Hay Mark thanks for the info. COuld you please point me to an example or code where I can refer to this setup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have solved both the issues with the setup below.

File **dirA/main.tf** contains something similar to

```
resource "local_file" "kubeconfig" {
  content  = module.gke_auth.kubeconfig_raw
  filename = "${path.module}/kubeconfig"
}

output "kubeconfig_file" {
  value = "${path.cwd}/kubeconfig"
}
```

File **dirB/main.tf** contains something similar to

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "kubeconfig_file" {
  backend = "local"

  config = {
    path = "${path.module}/../dirA/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path = "${data.terraform_remote_state.kubeconfig_file.outputs.kubeconfig_file}"
}
```

Finally:

```
cd dirA
terraform apply
cd ../dirB
terraform apply
```

*Note: In a similar way we can access variables from the stack in the different directory*